# ApiProtocolException Connection Error with NetApp API?

Tags: java, api, netapp, ontap

Using Net App Manageability SDK 9.8.

I am having a connection error I am encountering while attempting to connect to the NetApp storage system using the NetApp Manageability SDK. I have already performed some initial troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists. com.netapp.nmsdk.client.ApiProtocolException: Connection error to Storage System 10.32.0.206: Connection refused: connection

Protocol protocol = Protocol.HTTPS;

```
try {
    System.out.println("url is .." + url);
    ApiRunner apirunner = new ApiRunner(ApiTarget.builder()
        .withHost(url)
        .withUserName(REMOTE_USERNAME)
        .withPassword(REMOTE_PASSWORD)
        .withTargetType(TargetType.FILER)
        .useProtocol(protocol)
        .build()
    )
```

Troubleshooting Steps Performed:

Verified the accuracy of the IP address, username, and password.
Confirmed network connectivity to the storage system by pinging the IP address successfully.
Ensured that there are no firewall rules or network configurations blocking the connection.